# NaN while converting Value to Number in local Storage Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

I am getting NaN while trying to get the value from localStorage. Any pointers? The value is  value "488" before applying Number function.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PcUtilsService {

  constructor() { }

  // State Management
  setSession(key: string, value: any): void {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }
  getSession(key: string): number {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const value = localStorage.getItem(key) as string;
      console.log('value', Number(value));
      return Number(value);
    }
  }

  clearSession(): void {
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you also post what is the value of "value"?

Comment: Yes, added, THanks

Comment: any idea why are returning the local storage value as string? when you access the value from the local storage doesn`t it come as a string by default?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have done `JSON.stringify(value)` before saving, you need to do `JSON.parse(value)` before trying to convert it to `Number` on retrieval.

So, the code would be like : `Number(JSON.parse(value))`

Answer (score 0):

If the value is `"488"`, it is in fact a string. I would also just simplify this by removing `JSON.stringify` and use `+` to convert the string to number, like so:

```ts
this.setSession('key', '488');

// ...

setSession(key: string, value: string): void {
  localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  const a = +localStorage.getItem(key)
  console.log(a) // is now a number
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5jcbly)**